# Can't rename folders with KDE Dolphin

Tags: kde, rename, dolphin

When I try to rename a folder by changing the case (like changing it from /mnt/share/folder to /mnt/share/Folder) in Dolphin by either highlighting the folder name and pressing F2, or right-clicking > Rename, it prompts me with "Already Exists as Folder". It then prompts me to rename each file in the folder. When it finishes going through all the file renames, then I get "Error - Dolphin Could not rename folder /mnt/share/folder". Shouldn't I be able to change the case of a folder?

Comment: This is a limitation of NTFS even on Windows. Simply rename it to something with an extra letter, then to the case you want

Comment: Yes, thank you for both of those comments!